# Client-side downloading using in-app browsers

Tags: javascript, web, download

How should I be approaching the downloading blobs or files on the client-side for in-app browsers? Is there anything special that must be considered or resources I can be refered to?

I have been using my own downloading scripts, as well as the file-saver library by eligray, and they work for the majority of use-cases (apart from ChromeIOS) - however I simply haven't been able to get anything to work when they are linked through an app and I have no idea where to start.